# Assertj + how to disable stack trace

Tags: assertj

I want to disable the stack trace, as its kind of repetitive in all the test failures.

Kindly let me know, if there is any way possible.

at

```
ForAtleastOneTupleResult.getAssertionDone(ForAtleastOneTupleResult.java:57)


at org.assertj.core.api.AbstractSoftAssertions.throwsBestMultipleAssertionsError(AbstractSoftAssertions.java:198)
at org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.assertAll(SoftAssertions.java:131)
at com.xyz.assertion.ForAtleastOneTupleResult.getAssertionDone(ForAtleastOneTupleResult.java:71)
at com.xyz.regression.standard.PlacesTest.placesValidation(PlacesTest.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:71)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:14)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can, I believe this is part of the assertion error itself.
You can reduce the stack trace with http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#setRemoveAssertJRelatedElementsFromStackTrace-boolean- but it's only for the assertj section of the stack